# How does ternary operator use 3 operands?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

Ternary operators look like this

```
m = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

My teacher says that ternary operators use 3 operands

which here are `m`, `a` and `b`... 
even if `m` is actually the variable where we store the data...

But when we are writing

```
m = a + b;
```

Here as well we are writing `m` as the storing variable so why isn't this a ternary statement?

Comment: `m` is not an operand.

Comment: `(a>b)` is first operand, `a` is second, `b` is third.

Comment: `X ? Y : Z` - 3 operands. `X + Y` - 2 operands.

Comment: My teacher said that `m` is operand

Comment: In `m = a + b`, you actually have two operators, `=` and  `+`, each with two operands.

Comment: Also, the `?:` doesn't make a ternary *statement*: it's an *expression*.

Comment: `? :` is operator. `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `^`, `!`, etc. are all *operators*. Binary operators like `+` works on two *operands*.

Comment: If your teacher says that `m` is an operand of the ternary operator, then your teacher is mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m` is not an operand of either of the two operators (the ternary conditional operator and the `+` operator) whose number of operands you were asking about. It's just the variable two which you assign the result of these two operators.

The expression in your example is just `(a > b) ? a : b`, and the operands are `(a > b)`, `a` and `b`.

In `a + b`, the operands are `a` and `b`, so there are just two operands.

Note that my answer says nothing about the assignment operator `=`, which the question did not ask about.

Comment: `m` is an operand of the `=` assignment operator. [JLS 15.26. Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26): *the first operand of an assignment operator must be a variable.*

Comment: `?` and `:` are not 2 operators. It is 1 operator with 3 operands. [JLS 15.25. Conditional Operator `? :`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25): *The conditional operator has three operand expressions.*

Comment: @Andreas My answer was referring just to the ternary conditional operator and the `+` operator. I wasn't referring to the `=` operator anywhere. I clarified the answer.

Comment: @Andreas I never wrote that ? and : are 2 operators. The OP asked why the ternary conditional operator has 3 operands and the + operand does not. Those are the 2 operators I was referring to.

Comment: It was entirely unclear what operators you referred to, and is still not clear enough after your edit. It is misleading when the answer starts *"`m` is not an operand ..."*, because `m` is very definitely an operand in the shown code.

Comment: @Andreas yes, if you choose to read just the start of the sentence, it becomes incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the abstract syntax tree of

```
m = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

It would be something like:

```
ExpressionStatement       // m = (a > b) ? a : b;
  Assignment              // m = (a > b) ? a : b
    Identifier            // m
    ConditionalExpression //     (a > b) ? a : b
      Parenthesized       //     (a > b)
        BinaryOperator >  //      a > b
          Identifier      //      a
          Identifier      //          b
      Identifier          //               a
      Identifier          //                   b
```

The "ternary" refers to the fact that `ConditionalExpression` has 3 direct children in the tree (the parenthesized tree and the two identifiers).

The assignment is a binary tree, because it has two direct children (the identifier and the conditional expression).

The tree for `m = a + b;` would be:

```
ExpressionStatement  // m = a + b;
  Assignment         // m = a + b
    Identifier       // m
    BinaryOperator + //     a + b
      Identifier     //     a
      Identifier     //         b
```

Again (and always), the assignment is a binary operator, with two direct children: the identifier and the addition. The addition is a separate binary operator, with two direct children.

Answer (score 0):

The word `operands` does not refer to the variable used, but to the different part of the ternary operator. They are

- `result1` will be returned if the confition is evaluated to `True`
- `condition1` the condition to determine the result
- `result2` will be returned if the confition is evaluated to `False`

```
result1 if condition1 else result2
```

---

Then you use this in a print, or save it, but that is not a part of the ternary operator itself

```
print('Win' if value==15 else 'Loose') # print it
res = 55 if value%5==6 else 33         # save it
```

Answer (score 0):

The arity of an operator is determined by the number of operands / arguments. There are unary operators which take one operand like `i++` (post-increment), binary operators like `a + b` which take two arguments, and there is the **ternary** operator `a ? b : c` which takes three operands.

Operands can use the same variable or expression. For example, in the expression `a + a`, the `+` operator is still a *binary* operator that takes two arguments - it just takes the same argument twice.

`m = <expression>` is an assignment. The assignment operator is also a binary operator that takes two arguments. On the left-hand side you have the target of the assignment, which is the variable `m` in your case, and on the right hand side you have the (complex) expression that gives the value.

This leaves you with `(a > b) ? a : b`. There are still three operands - the conditional is `(a > b)`, the `a` is the *true expression*, and the `b` is the *false expression*.

This operator is defined in [§15.25 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> **The conditional operator has three operand expressions**. `?` appears between the first and second expressions, and `:` appears between the second and third expressions.
>   (Highlight mine).